How to handle the possibility of expected null properties in a LINQ were clause?
Consider the following C# Code Fragment:
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string? Name { get; set;}
    public string? Description {get; set;}
}


List<Person>? _persons = new List<Person>();

// Something populates the _persons list;

//Use LINQ like this.
Person? person = _persons. Where (person=>person.Name == "someName").FirstOrDefault();


In the LINQ a CS8602 warning is raised because person.Name has the possibility of being null. Based on the Person Class this is definitely possible and expected.  However, in that case the null is not equal to "someName" so I would not expect records that have their name property set to null to not be returned anyway.
Is there a syntax that will permit the query without having this warning?  I am using .Net 8 and Visual Studio 2022.
Thanks

Are you sure the warning isn't caused by _persons? It's List<Person>? .

@PekoMiko The line is ending with .FirstOrDefault() which results a single object (or null), not a list.

@Mitchell , OP is accessing as _persons.Where(), which is why I am worried. Not sure about VS, but the yellow squiggle shows up testing on JetBrains Rider for me.

The warning is caused because of the possibility that the description property of the Person Class can be null.

Personally, I always avoid using nulls when working with LINQ. Your code might change in the future, depending on the size so it becomes more robust.
Person? person = _persons.Where(person => person.Name != null && person.Name == "someName").FirstOrDefault();

However, if you still want to ignore the null warning, you can use the null-forgiving operator "!"
Person? person = _persons.Where(person => person.Name! == "someName").FirstOrDefault();


You could use Equals(), like
person=>"someName".Equals(person.Name)

